# How to change links from \\myserver-old\sharedfolder back to \\myserver\\sharedfolder?

Tags: windows, network-share

We replaced an old server with shared folder with a new server.

1. We had a shared folders on server with network name `\\myserver`
2. Admin renamed it to `\\myserver-old` (not sure what method he used), and moved shared folders to a new server names `\\newserver`
3. Unfortunately, all links to the shared folder have been updated to `\\myserver-old`

Is it possible to update the links back to `\\newserver\...`?

Comment: It is possible to programmatically modify shortcuts. Not trivial though. Given that the remainder of this environment is probably commensurate with the "migration", why not just create a DNS CNAME for `myserver-old` to point to `newserver`? For future reference, it is usually way less painful and easier to maintain the existing server name during these "migrations". Instead of the worst practice rename bombs that seem to be floating around.

Comment: @GregAskew: agreed, but I'm just a poor external developer who got bugreports.
IT infrastracture maintenance is outsourced and they said "We don't upgrade old windows servers" :O

Comment: `IT infrastructure maintenance is outsourced` That's who you should be interfacing with. For all we know they are already working on a solution. It's important to keep those lines of communication open.